# Does CoAP allow multiple oustanding (ACKed) CON Requests when NSTART is 1

Tags: coap

According to the CoAP RFC, NSTART is a limit on the number of outstanding interactions.
But it describes an outstanding interaction as:

> either a CON for which an ACK has not    yet been received but is
> still expected (message layer) or a request    for which neither a
> response nor an Acknowledgment message has yet    been received but is
> still expected (which may both occur at the same    time, counting as
> one outstanding interaction)

This would seem to imply that if an empty ACK has been received for a CON request, but the matching response has not yet been received, it is okay to send a new CON request (with a different token of course) without violating NSTART=1.  Is this interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from the IETF core mailing list, confirming that NSTART is not a constraint on the number of concurrent, ACK'd CON requests:

> > Does this wording imply that concurrent CON requests (ACK'ed, but for which a CON response is still expected) are acceptable if NSTART=1?
>
> Yes.
>
> > If an empty ACK has been received for a CON request, may a new CON request be sent before a CON response has been received for the first
> > request, without violating the NSTART=1 constraint?
>
> Yes.
>
> The idea is that the fact that the CON did receive an ACK (and the
> latency taken for that) indicates that the path is not heavily
> suggested, or that the necessary slow-down has been achieved (by the
> original RTT, and by wait times before retransmission).
>
> The server will independently congestion-control their separate
> responses.

Answer (score 1):

In my memory, it's years ago, that we had such discussions about that. First at all, if you really want a qualified answer, please try the [core-mailing-list](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/browse/core/) or create an issue in [Corrections and Clarifications](https://github.com/core-wg/corrclar)

For me, NSTART-1 play mainly a role in congestion control. So the very first question will be, if your devices, server, or network is rather constrained? If you violate the NSTART-1 in a constraint use-case, you will get more drops and so also more retries and that results in more inefficiency.

If NSTART-1 sticks now to a "constrained transmission layer" or a "constrained application layer", may give you the answer. If it's the transmission layer, you don't want to overload that. That means, you only have one exchange in flight. And you not only wait for the ACK, you also wait for the response, otherwise a new request may cross the response and results in overload. But that are all just assumption. In many cases neither the network-layer nor the application-layer is that constrained and with that, you may also relax that from one open "request-response-exchange" to one open "con/ack".
Finally, if you implement and server, don't force NSTART-1, that makes in my experience more trouble than it helps.

Comment: I think congestion control is handled by the fact that only one unacknowledged CON can be in flight at a time.  But once a CON request is acked, it may take an arbitrary amount of time for the CON response to be sent.  That can cause a bottleneck where requests must be queued waiting for a slow response.  I'm wondering if I must open a new connection, potentially with a new DTLS establishment, in order to avoid the backlog.  I am trying to avoid one long duration request from causing starvation.  Thank you for the links.

Comment: "But once a CON request is acked, it may take an arbitrary amount of time for the CON response to be sent." In my experience, it only works, if the response is sent within a few seconds. Otherwise, NATs will nettle you ;-).

Comment: "I'm wondering if I must open a new connection, potentially with a new DTLS establishment, in order to avoid the backlog." No, no new connection! That doesn't help, if the "wire" or "peers" are constrained. Please, NSTART-1 is to protect constrained networks and peers. If your application assumes not constrained networks and peers, then just relax NSTART-1. The only topic, where I recommend to stick to NSTART-1 is until you verified, that the other peer is reachable at all (first message received back does this.)

Comment: "I think congestion control is handled by the fact that only one unacknowledged CON can be in flight at a time." That's not always enough. Consider half-duplex communication, then it's better to wait. So let me repeat, the culprit is to design "long lasting exchanges". So just don't design responses, which take more than a few couple of seconds.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback.  I did post to core mailing list and got a quick response to my question.  They confirmed that NSTART does not limit outstanding requests that have been acked.  Once an ACK to a CON request has been received, a new CON request may be sent, without violating NSTART=1.  That is what I was hoping was true.

Comment: In my experience (more than 5 years), the point is more, what has been considered by that definition. You may comply to the RFC, but if your reality is different to the assumed one in the RFC, the guidance may fail. In your case, if you get too many 4.29/5.03, because your server's application layer is overloaded, then you may just check, if waiting for a response is better.